# How to load/unload a graph from a session in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am working on a project of mine where I have to classify images of the American Sign Language of the entire alphabet aswell as digits.

I have retrained the final layer of the Inception v3 model from Tensorflow. Since some number symbols from the ASL are identical to letter symbols, I decided to train two different models. As a result, I have two logs folders: `number_logs` and `letters_logs`. Inside these folders, you can find a graph definition and the labels corresponding to the classes (a, b, ... and 0, 1, ...)

**I would like to be able to either have two sessions open or find a way to load and unload one of the graphs to do the classification for either letters or numbers.** Current code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Example with number classification
with tf.Session() as sess:
    self.label_lines = [lines.rstrip() for line in \
        tf.gfile.GFile('numbers_logs/trained_labels.txt')]

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('numbers_logs/trained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(self.graph_def, name='')
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    image_data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]
    classified_symbol = label_lines[top_k[0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fidling around, I found out running two sessions with different graphs will work. It seems I can't juste close a session and reopen it as I please with different graphs.

```
import tensorflow as tf

self.label_lines_numbers = [lines.rstrip() for line in \
    tf.gfile.GFile('numbers_logs/trained_labels.txt')]

self.label_lines_letters = [lines.rstrip() for line in \
    tf.gfile.GFile('letters_logs/trained_labels.txt')]

with tf.gfile.FastGFile('numbers_logs/trained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    graph = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

sess_numbers = tf.Session(graph)
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.gfile.FastGFile('letters_logs/trained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    graph = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

sess_letters = tf.Session(graph)

softmax_tensor_numbers = sess_numbers.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

softmax_tensor_letters = sess_letters.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

# Proceed with classification
```